# Arduino: If else statement, if all numbers are in range, if at least one is not?

Tags: arduino

I have 4 variables that will be populated, if all the numbers in within a certain range then they're in the dead zone. If at least one is out of the range then the else statement is evoked.

My problem is that sometimes when all the numbers are in range, the else statement will occur, and I'm not sure why.

```cpp
boolean isPushed(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    //460 TO 533 is the deadzone
    //joysticks must be outside of this range to be considered pushed
    boolean pushed;
    int minZone = 420;
    int maxZone = 533;

    Serial.println("*****************");
    if ((analogRead(X_pin_1) >= minZone && analogRead(X_pin_1) <= maxZone) &&
        (analogRead(X_pin_2) >= minZone && analogRead(X_pin_2) <= maxZone) &&
        (analogRead(Y_pin_1) >= minZone && analogRead(Y_pin_1) <= maxZone) &&
        (analogRead(Y_pin_2) >= minZone && analogRead(Y_pin_2) <= maxZone))
    { 
        Serial.println("NOT PUSHED. Inside deadzone.");
        pushed = false;
    }
    else 
    { 
        pushed = true; 
        Serial.println("PUSHED");
        Serial.print("X1 = ");
        Serial.println(analogRead(X_pin_1));
        Serial.print("Y1 = ");
        Serial.println(analogRead(Y_pin_1));
        Serial.print("X2 = ");
        Serial.println(analogRead(X_pin_2));
        Serial.print("Y2 = ");
        Serial.println(analogRead(Y_pin_2));
    }

    return pushed;
}
```

For example, this is one of the outputs:

```
*****************
PUSHED
X1 = 495
Y1 = 481
X2 = 478
Y2 = 530
***************
```

Please tell me why!

Answer (score 3):

You are reading each pin multiple times at different time intervals, so the same pin could have a different value each time you read it.

Instead, you should store the value of each pin in a variable before the `if` statement:

```
int val_x_pin_1 = analogRead(X_pin_1);
...
```

And then use those variables in the rest of the code (also in your `print` statements):

```
if ((val_x_pin_1 >= minZone && val_x_pin_1 <= maxZone)
   && ...
```